# Hibernate Object mapping issue

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hql

I have couple of database tables:

```
User (user_id, firstName, lastName)
```

and

```
Product (id, name, user_id)
```

`user_id` is acting as foreign key in here.

I have a couple of classes below.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    /*getters setter are omitted.*/
}
```

& the other is

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "packing")
    private int packing;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User us) {
        this.user = us;
    }
        /* other getters setter are omitted.*/
}
```

My `ProductDao.java` class has this query:

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
Iterator<?> products = session.createQuery(" SELECT id, name, user FROM Product ") .list().iterator();
```

If I remove `user` from this query, it works well (though doesn't fetch the User details for `user`)

Please guide me where I am missing to fetch all the details of specific `user`.

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing a regular SQL query, while you probably want to issue a HQL or JPQL query. The important difference is that while SQL operates on DB columns, HQL operates on entities.Since there is no `user` column in the Product table, you will not get the desired result.

Please try this: `SELECT p FROM Product p`.

If you explicitly want only the mapped properties and not the entity itself, try
`SELECT p.id, p.name, p.user FROM Product p`. Note that as HQL operates on entities, you need the dot operator and can use field names instead of column names.

Comment: Thanks for you help. It shows all the data from `Product` but `user`.
I am still unable to get data for `user`.

Comment: The reason might be the lazy loading. Is the user field `null` or are you getting an Exception? Are you accessing the filed in a transaction? Have you tried eagerly fetching the user by either changing the annotation to `FetchType.EAGER` or adding `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to the query?

Comment: I am getting user field 'null' in debugging.
Yes, I have tried using EAGER and LAZY as well.
I see `user=null` in debugging mode, but when I print the object (converted into JSON) it doesn't show `user` field.

Comment: Hmm, this is unexpected. Your mapping looks right and eager fetching with a correct query should take care of resolving the reference. Can you confirm that the data is correctly mapped and stored in the DB, meaning that the row in the PRODUCT table has the foreign key in it's user_id column and that the corresponding user exists? Sorry for the trivial question, but otherwise I have no clue :)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with `user` table, and `Product` table does have a key `user_id` in it.
Thanks for your help.
Would you please help If I share git repo with you?